# Correct configuration of rapidoid

Tags: rapidoid

I'm trying to customize the configuration of rapidoid in the config files. In my case I'm using the config-mysql.yml file, since I'm connecting to a mysql database.

Besides the jdbc configuration stuff, I've the following configuration in config-mysql.yml:

```
on:
  port: 8888
  address: 0.0.0.0

net:
  port: 8888
  address: 0.0.0.0
```

When I start my application I can see the following in the log:

```
[server] INFO  o.r.net.impl.RapidoidServerLoop - Starting server | address = 0.0.0.0 | port = 8888 | I/O workers = 1 | sync = true | accept = non-blocking
[main] INFO  org.rapidoid.setup.Setup - Server has started | setup = main | home = http://localhost:8888
```

And if I check with netstat, I only see a binding to the port 8888 for tcp6 and not tcp, as follows:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related with a bad configuration which was generating an exception, which I did not notice before.

To force the configuration values I'm used the following code:

```
App.bootstrap(args, "profiles=mysql,prod", "on.address=0.0.0.0", "on.port=8886" ).jpa();
```

Thanks.